# lock screen-qml

Tags: qt, qml

from past 1 week i am trying to solve this issue. i am not able to lock my screen of whatever pages i create. i tried putting timer. but i am not getting how should i detect if the user is not active.
for example
ex1.qml

```
rectangle{
id:ex1
color:"red"
keys.onReturnPressed:{
ex2.visble=true;
visible=false;
}
rectangle {
id:ex2
color:"blue"
keys.onReturnPressed:{
visible=false;
ex1.visible=true;
}
}
}
```

if the user is not active for some time then the application should ask for password the unlock it. if the user is not pressing enter key for 2 mins then it should lock the screen and ask for password.
how to do it???

i am waiting for your answer. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
FocusScope{
    height: 500;
    width:500;
    focus: true;
    Rectangle {
        id:ex1
        color:"red"
        focus: ex1.visible;
        visible:true;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        Keys.onEnterPressed: {
            lockTimer.restart();
        }
        Keys.onReturnPressed:{
            lockTimer.restart();
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        id:ex2
        color:"blue";
        focus: !ex1.visible;
        visible: !ex1.visible;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        Keys.onReturnPressed:{
            password.opacity=1;
        }
        Text {
            id: password;
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            opacity: 0;
            text: "Enter Password"
        }
    }

Timer{
    id:lockTimer;
    repeat: false;
    onTriggered: {
        ex2.visible=true;
        ex1.visible=false;
    }
}

function setTimer(val){
    lockTimer.interval=60000*val;
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    setTimer(2);
    lockTimer.start();
}
```

}